# YouTube API v3 - captions upload causes HTTP 500 backend error

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I'm using the code sample for how to use the YouTube v3 API methods to upload YouTube video caption tracks, given at:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#create_and_manage_youtube_video_caption_tracks

However, when I'm running it from the command line using the following command:

```
python manage_captions.py --file="test.srt" --videoid='dDiL1fbAIdA' --action='upload'
```

The content of test.rst is:

```
First line of caption track: 1
00:00:23,000 --> 00:00:25,000
This text displays for two seconds starting
1 minute and 23 seconds into the video.

2
00:02:20,250 --> 00:02:23,800
This text displays from 2 minutes and 20.25 seconds after the start
of the video until 2 minutes and 23.8 seconds after the start of the video.

3
00:03:14,159 --> 00:03:22,092
This text displays beginning 3 minutes and 14.159 seconds
after the start of the video for an undefined length of time.
```

I get an HTTP error:

```
An HTTP error 500 occurred:
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

Any ideas for why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add --language='en' to the call since it's a required field.

Comment: It is 'en' by default

Answer (score 0):

After trying again today, I was able to upload the captions successfully. Not sure what has changed, but the error did not repeat although I didn't change anything.